# WCF service client configuration from appsetting.json (.NET Core)

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, .net-core

Is there any way to configure WCF Service Reference from configuration file? I would like to configure WCF service reference with such settings as SecurityMode, Address, ReaderQuotas etc. I would also like to be able to choose between WsHttpBinding, BasicHttpBinding, BasicHttpsBinging etc (like normal configuration provided by app.config in .NET Framework).

Is there any way to achive that in .NET Core/.NET Standard?

Thank, Bartek

Comment: If you mean how to access appsetting.json config variable from .NET Core, you can use IConfigurationRoot, if not please specify with detail what you need.

Comment: No. I know how to Access ConfigurationRoot and map it to c# objects. But I dont know to how retrieve diffrent binding type like basichttpaccesss, WsHttpBinding etc. All of them inherits from Binding. And I want to know if i have to configure WCF client from c#, or can it be automaticly like in. NET Framework.

Comment: I've reached to this purpose by reading this article:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/wcf-client-overview
I hope you do too

Comment: @BartekChyży
So, is there a way to automatically configure WCF client from appsettings or another file? It seems that .NET core does not support configuring WCF clients this way. You have to write it yourself, do you?

Answer (score 2):

Certain binding, such as `Wshttpbinding`,`Netnamedbinding` is not compatible with DotNet Core framework. Consequently, we could not configure it. However, this doesn’t represent that we can’t configure `Basichttpbinding`, `Nettcpbinding`.
At present, the WCF service cannot be created by using DotNet Core without using the third-party library. Moreover, WCF client based on DotNet Core just a compatible workaround.
https://github.com/dotnet/wcf
Like the DotNet Framework project, Microsoft Corporation provides Microsoft WCF Web Service Reference Provider tool to generate a client proxy.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/wcf-web-service-reference-guide
After adding connected service, it shall generate a new namespace contains the client proxy class. Most of the client configuration located in the `Reference.cs`.
Also, we could manually program the code to call the WCF service.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //using the automatically generated client proxy lcoated in the Reference.cs file to call the service.
            //ServiceReference1.ServiceClient client = new ServiceReference1.ServiceClient();
            //var result = client.TestAsync();
            //Console.WriteLine(result.Result);

            //using the Channel Factory to call the service.
            Uri uri = new Uri("http://10.157.13.69:21012");
            BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
            ChannelFactory<IService> factory = new ChannelFactory<IService>(binding, new EndpointAddress(uri));
            IService service = factory.CreateChannel();
            var result = service.Test();
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
    }
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string Test();

    }
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-use-the-channelfactory
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Comment: But can I configure it with appsettiggs.json? I dont want to hardcode bindings configuration. I dont know how to model my configuration to be able to read all binding type like basichttpbinding, basichttpsbinding etc. To sum up i want to find the way to read any of bindigconfiguration from appsetting.json

Comment: I don’t know some official implementation about this, but the below links might be instrumental for you.
https://www.seeleycoder.com/blog/using-wcf-with-dotnetcore/   ,  
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44462093/inject-service-reference-into-net-with-appsettings-json-and-startup-cs

Comment: inject the configuration then `var uri = new Uri(configuration.GetValue<string>("soapUrl"));`